# Statistically significant difference in R^2 between two linear regression models

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, bootstrap

We are interested in if the difference in R^2 between two linear regression models is statistically significant (the metric of model performance doesn't necessarily have to be R^2 but that is what we are using so far). In the end we would need a p-value for the significance of their difference. We thought of using the likelihood ratio test but the models are not nested.

We are planning to bootstrap the samples in each model (with 5,000 replicates), and then calculate R^2 for each replicate such that there is a distribution of R^2 values for each model (alternately we were thinking of getting the difference in R^2 between the bootstrap replicates and then testing the single distribution of R^2 differences).

How can we compare the two bootstrapped R^2 distributions for the null hypothesis that their means are different (or alternately, test the null hypothesis that the distribution of difference in R^2 values is not equal to 0)? I don't think a t-test would be appropriate since the significance of its result would be greatly affected by the number of bootstrap replicates (although all the bootstrapped distributions appear very normal; did not bother with any normality tests).

I've been able to find similar questions posted here and on other message boards, but I cannot find solutions that would give a p-value. Thanks.

Comment: I’m thinking of a permutation test to see how unusual your difference in $R^2$ is. The probability of getting your observed difference in $R^2$ or more extreme is the p-value,

Comment: Differences in $R^2$ have scarcely any meaning, either practical or conceptual.  Could you therefore explain why you propose to test differences?  You might consider evaluating *ratios* of $1-R^2,$ because that tests differences in the spreads of the error terms.

Comment: Essentially we are interested in the predictive power of some variable in the model:
outcome ~ some_variable + covariates, where some_variable can be processed in many different ways. We want to see if different ways of processing this variable can lead to statistically significant differences in predictive power (doesn't have to necessarily be R^2). 
We could probably evaluate ratios of 1-R^2, but I'm still not sure how to get significance of differences, preferably with a p-value.